# Scheduling Codeigniter php file in Windows Task Scheduler with controller name and function without using Cron

Tags: php, powershell, codeigniter, windows-task-scheduler

[image: Task Scheduler Log]
I'm trying to schedule a codeigniter php file in Windows Task Scheduler.
I have tried using .bat file as follows:

```
php E:\UniServerZ\index.php mailtry mailsend
```

where `mailtry` is controller name and `mailsend` is controller function

I have also tried scheduling using powershell script using url as follows:

First:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command
        Invoke-WebRequest 'https://abcd.hub/abcd/mailtry/mailsend' -UseBasicParsing
```

Second:

```
$url = "https://abcd.hub/abcd/mailtry/mailsend"
PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method GET
```

Third:

```
explorer "https://abcd.hub/abcd/mailtry/mailsend"
```

Nothing works. How to schedule this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `Nothing works` isn't a useful description of your problem. What _exactly_ goes wrong when you try these various approaches? We can't fix a problem if we don't know what the specific fault is, and we also don't know what your PHP code looks like.

Comment: Nothing works here means upon scheduling these, nothing happens. Literally! No errors and no warnings. I haven't provided php code as I just want to schedule it.

Comment: So, are you saying that if you put `https://abcd.hub/abcd/mailtry/mailsend` into your browser it would work no problem and send the mail?

Comment: have you tested these command-line approaches independently without the scheduler? E.g. if you open a powershell window and write one of your attempts such as `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method GET` , does it send the request? You can use a network monitor to test, if you don't get any output from powershell directly, and/or you can check the server logs, see if it received the request or not, and what status code it had. In other words, there's plenty more debugging you can do here to discover precisely what is happening / not happening. Narrow it down.

Comment: 1. Yes. When I give only the URL in browser, it'll work without any errors
2. Yes. I tried in powershell window. It works in powershell window and when I save the same as .ps1 script and schedule, it doesn't.

Comment: Did you look in the history in your task to see if it has any error information in there? Sometimes it will tell you if the previous attempts to run the task succeeded or failed, or what the result was.

Comment: BTW if you save it in .ps1 file then it would need to be just `Invoke-WebRequest...` not `PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest...` (I'm talking about the 2nd attempt). It's the task config which would need to invoke the powershell executable. Since the problem only occurs once you actually try to schedule it, I think you need to show us exactly how you configured the task.

Comment: Yes I checked that, too. No errors even there.

Comment: Yes. I have tried without `powershell` also, since it didn't work, later I included this.

Comment: Including that in the actual ps1 file won't help you. Show the task config, please

Comment: Yes. Uploaded in the above section

Comment: Have you also checked the access log to see if your PHP gets any requests at all? It might not produce an actual error but still fail to do what it suppose to do for some unknown reason?

Comment: That picture is just the history by the looks of it. That's not the configuration of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hoping that if you go on a browser and execute that link it
> successfully works.

Then you can actually configure a task scheduler to open a certain browser then go for that link to execute.[image]

At step 1 from the image put a path for a browser program like Firefox or google chrome within double quotes.
e.g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

Then at step 2, simply add a link you wish to execute.

Then save your Task, you are done from there.

Reference: https://windowsloop.com/open-webpage-on-schedule-task-scheduler/

**All the Best**

Comment: Sure you're welcome, don't forget to give some credits @AnushreeBharadwaj